# Find Highest Number in Column of Strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have a column with the following string schema

```
saras-2009-0007-10.23
saras-2009-0008-9.01
saras-2009-0009-12.13
```

I'm trying to develop a formula that searches the column, and finds the highest numerical value, and puts that number in a cell

(ex: 0007, 0008, 0009)

0009 will be returned

The string schema never changes, and always looking for the characters in that position.

Comment: you will need to explain more why 0007, 0008, 0009 are the highest?  Highest would indicate one return not three.

Comment: 0009 is the highest number in this example

Comment: okay but why extract that number and not 2009 or 12.13

Comment: edited for clarity

I need the correct number returned in the correct position because each value represents a different thing.

This is tracking inventory, and 2009 is the date, and 12.13 is the price .. and those change depending on the inventory, and aren't increasing +1 every time

Comment: so we can ignore all other numbers and compare only the middle set of numbers?  are the strings always `####-####-#0.00`?

Comment: Have a look into splitting cells into an array through filterxml. From there it shouldn't be too hard to grab the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=MAX(--MID(A1:A3,12,4))
```

with proper formatting:

[image]

This may require an **array formula**:

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Works great!  Can also confirm it works in google sheets with ```=ArrayFormula(MAX(--MID(L2:L1000,12,4)))```

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula in Office 365 subscription use  FILTERXML:

```
=TEXT(MAX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"-","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[3]")),"0000")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried in O2016 and it did not work, and I could not manipulate it to work.

Comment: Not what I expected but indeed you are correct